# Run an executable and read logs at the same time

Tags: bash, docker, unix

I have a scenario where I run an executable (as an entrypoint) from a docker container.
The problem is, that executable doesn't write logs to stdout, but to a file.

I need a way to run that executable in the foreground (so that if it crashes, it crashes the container as well), but pipe logs from a file to stdout at the same time.

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Can you provide the commands you are running?

Comment: Can't you just mount a volume to where the log file is being written?

Comment: @Paolo I can, but I need the logs in stdout (that's the only way our logging system will catch them)

Comment: Do you have control over how this image is built or are you just given it?

Comment: @seqre I basically have this program (I don't have control over its source code), that I run from the command line `ENTRYPOINT ["myprogram"]`, it writes logs to `/var/log`

Comment: @Paolo I'm working with a base image (which I don't have control over), but I can wrap that base image in my own docker file and write whatever command I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux environment provides a couple of special files that actually relay to other file descriptors.  If you set the log file to `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/fd/1`, it will actually appear on the main process's stdout.

The [Docker Hub `nginx` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) has a neat variation on this.  If you look at its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/d496baf859613adfe391ca8e7615cc7ec7966621/mainline/debian/Dockerfile#L101-L102) it specifies:

```sh
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

The Nginx application configuration specifies its log file as `/var/log/nginx/access.log`.  If you do nothing, that is a symlink to `/dev/stdout`, and so access logs appear in the `docker logs` output.  But if you'd prefer to have the logs in files, you can bind-mount a host directory on `/var/log/nginx` and you'll get `access.log` on the host as a file instead.

Comment: I don't have control over which file the program logs to, but you're saying I can symlink it to `/dev/stdout`?

Comment: tested, and it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

G'day areller!
Well, your question is quite generic/abstract (as David Maze mentioned, you didn't said what are the exact commands neither how are you running them), but i think i got it.

You will do the following:

```
# if the command logs to the stdout, do:
command &> /var/tmp/command.log &
tail -f /var/tmp/command.log
# if the command logs to an specific file in, idk, /var/adm, do:
tail -f /specific/file/directory/command.log
```

Instead of explaining `tail -f` by myself, i will take a citation from the [`tail(1p)` manual page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/tail/):

> `-f`     If the input file is a regular file or if the file operand specifies a FIFO, do not terminate after the last line of the input  file
> has been copied, but read and copy further bytes from the input file when they become available. If no file operand is specified and
> standard input is a pipe, the -f option shall be ignored. If the input file is not a FIFO, pipe, or regular file, it is  unspecified
> whether or not the -f option shall be ignored.

I hope i've helped you.